# html: Too much white space in table

Tags: html, jsp

I am trying to write a jsp that will show the errors for a form, however I can't seem to format it properly. I tried to add a table in one of the cells, which made it look a bit better, but it still doesn't look clean. This is my code.

```html
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
 pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>New user account</title>
</head>
<body>

 <h1 align="center">Sign Up</h1>
 <h3 align="center">Please fill in the following form to create
  your account.</h3>
 <form action="SignupCheck" method="post">
  <table border="1" align=center width="500">
   <tr>
    <td width="250"><p align="center">Full Legal Name:</p></td>
    <td align="center"><input type="text" name="name"></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td width="250"><p align="center">Username:</p>
    <td align="center"><input type="text" name="username"></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td width="250"><p align="center">Password:</p></td>
    <td align="center"><input type="password" name="password"></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td width="250"><p align="center">Confirm Password:</p></td>
    <td align="center"><input type="password"
     name="confirmPassword"></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td width="250"><p align="center">Starting Balance:</p></td>
    <td>
     <table align="center">
      <tr>
       <td align="center"><input type="text" name="balance"></td>

      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td align="center"><p align="center"
         style="color: red; font-size: 18px">Please enter your
         password</p></td>
      </tr>
     </table>
    </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td width="250" align="right"><input type="reset" value="Reset"></td>
    <td align="left"><input type="submit" value="Submit"></td>
   </tr>
  </table>
 </form>
</body>
</html>
```

As you see I placed a sample error and the Textbox is too high and the error message takes up too much space...

Comment: Eventually you'll learn that HTML can and most likely will look horrific the harder the code works.

Comment: Look into CSS, it will give you loads of control over the formatting of your HTML element and allow you to have a much smaller and cleaner HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following as CSS:

```
td {
    padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px
}
p {
    text-align:right;
}
table {
    border: solid lightgray;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
```

[Here is the **JSFiddle** demo](https://jsfiddle.net/hoL7o9r8/)

Also note that I modified the HTML code, removing the sub-table you added. Please have a look at the JSFiddle for the full code.